# Finding a probability with XOR

Tags: xor

Suppose x,y are two positive integers with n bits. Find the probability such that P(x+y=x^y) where ^ denotes XOR. My teacher gave me this problem. He said the answer is 1/2+1/2^{n+1}. But I had found some different answer. Can someone help me? 
My try :
For n=1, the probability is 3/4. Now suppose we have found the probability for n bit. Then to extend to n+1, we have 2 valid cases out of all possible 3 cases. So. The probability becomes (2/3)^n*3/4. But this is not working. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Comment: How are you handling overflow for the `x+y` case ? For `n = 1, x = 1, y = 1` you could say that `x+y == x^y` or `x+y != x^y`, depending on how you handle the overflow.

Comment: This is just a guess, but if he is considering the base probability to be 3/4, then, that means `n=1,x=1,y=1` implies `x+y != x^y`. Otherwise the probability is 1, right? Am I correct here?

Comment: @shadow10: I think you're right, and I think I can now see where the `1/2+1/2^(n+1)` comes from - you just consider the XOR operation to be N half-adders, and then you get a mismatch only when there is a carry out from one or more bits.

Comment: Can you explain a bit? I found this to be interesting, but I didn't get anywhere with it. @PaulR I am not too familiar with half-adders, can this be explained in novice terms? I am only learning programming very recently. Sorry if this request is a bit unexpected, all the while at someone else's post.

Comment: I have read about half adder, and I understand it, but how does the idea is incorporated here? Can you help me @PaulR, I hope it is not too trouble. Thanks. (sorry I can't seem to edit my previous message)

Comment: Sure - the XOR operation is also known as a half-adder, as it gives the correct result for addition, except that it doesn't generate a carry when you add two `1`s. It also doesn't support a carry input. So you can add two N bit values by XOR-ing all the bits and implementing some additional logic to handle carry-in/carry-out. If you didn't have this additional logic for carry-in/carry-out then your adder would only work correctly when the inputs for each bit were `00`, `10` or `01` (i.e. no carry), and would fail for `11`. So for random inputs each bit "works" as an adder with probability 3/4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60100/discussion-between-shadow10-and-paul-r).

Comment: Sorry, @PaulR could you please post the solution or something? I can't seem to get into the chat(internet problems, my apologies) , and it is hard to understand, how to apply the half-adder concept to this problem. Thanks a lot. :(

Comment: Sorry - I have to go now - re-read my edited comment above though, and look up half-adder on Wikipedia. I'll be back tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

The solution your teacher gave you appears to be wrong. It should be:

```
P = (3/4)^n
```

for the strict case, where overflow is not ignored, or

```
P = (3/4)^(n-1)
```

for the lax case, where overflow is ignored.

I have verified this with a simple brute force test program which just evaluates all possible inputs for a given n.